# About nilpotent Jordan algebras, matrix representations and formally real algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, roots-of-unity, nilpotent-matrices

Given an non-commutative associative unital algebra A of characteristic $0$, one can construct a Jordan algebra $A+$ using the same underlying addition vector space.
Notice first that an associative algebra is a Jordan algebra if and only if it is commutative.
To make it commutative we can define a new multiplication on $A$ to make it commutative, and in fact make it a Jordan algebra. The new multiplication $x ∘ y$ is the Jordan product:

$$(xy + yx)/2$$

This defines a unital Jordan algebra $A+$, and we call these unital Jordan algebras, as well as any unital subalgebras of these Jordan algebras, "special unital Jordan algebras".

Ok, now I was wondering:

1. Can all such special unital Jordan algebras be constructed and representated as above from some matrix algebra $B$ where the elements of the matrix are reals?
2. Does that matrix algebra $B$ always contain (non-zero) nilpotent elements $b^2 = 0$?
3. If 1) is 'no' ,does $A+$ always contain (non-zero) nilpotent elements $a^2 = 0$?
4. If 1) is 'yes', do $A+$ and $B$ both have elements that are square roots of $-1$ If at least one of them does?
5. An algebra over the real numbers is said to be formally real if it satisfies the property that a sum of $n$ squares can only vanish if each one vanishes individually.

If $A+$ is constructed from matrix algebra $B$ as described above, does that imply it is formally real?

I found this paper, not sure if it helps.

https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-16/issue-1/Some-identities-valid-in-special-Jordan-algebras-but-not-valid/pjm/1102995084.full

Maybe the ideas of tensors help me out, since they generalize matrices ?

Im no expert at this.